# How to add website to iphone/ipad address book?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, abaddressbook

how can i add a website to the contacts of the iphone/ipad address book?
I managed to add email, phone numbers, but i cannot did the same with a site.
Presently, i'm using this code to have the site written in the address book and displayed, but clicking on it i get displayed the form to write an email

```
        const CFStringRef siteLabel = CFSTR("Site");
        ABMutableMultiValueRef multiEmail = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail, sito, siteLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty, multiEmail, &error);
        CFRelease(multiEmail);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `kABPersonSocialProfileProperty` property and `kABPersonSocialProfileURLKey` key.

e.g.:

```
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiURL = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiURL, url, siteLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonSocialProfileURLKey, multiURL, &error);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as i launch this the Ipad crashesd. It said: Can't return type callbacks for 46
2013-01-23 11:17:59.357 Myapp[15926:907] -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8d4a00
2013-01-23 11:17:59.363 ForumPalermo[15926:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8d4a00'
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Solved! Changin something here and there! Thank you! 

ABMutableMultiValueRef multiURL = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiURL, url, siteLabel, NULL);
            ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonURLProperty, multiURL,&error);
            CFRelease(multiURL);

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the code by Paul, modified a little!

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiURL = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);          
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiURL, url, siteLabel, NULL); 
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonURLProperty, multiURL,&error); 
CFRelease(multiURL);
```

Comment: I had a typo in my code - can't compile in my head yet!  My reading is that you should be using kABPersonSocialProfileProperty, although your solution will work.  Please also accept my answer :-).

Comment: it is allows return 0  until the user marge the Social contacts with native and this does not happened until he try to delete the Facebook account for example in that case alert appear and ask if u wanna to marge contacts or not ??? other wise return 0 values :)